# Facebook Credits Demo Application returning error

Tags: javascript, facebook, credits, facebook-credits

We are participating in the Facebook Credits beta. After approval of our live app, we followed the steps from the API page to set up the demo application:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi

However, whenever we submit with the "Pay with Facebook" button, we are getting back error 1383008 ("The application you are using is not responding").

We've checked the server logs and confirmed that all necessary params are passing to http://apps.facebook.com/ajax/flows/?__a=1 as expected. We've also confirmed that the callback URL (callback.php from the demo app files) is never being hit.

Just to be certain this isn't a compatibility issue with the new JavaScript SDK, we set up the demo using the old JS SDK and got the same error.

Has anyone else experienced this issue with running the demo application (using either version of the SDK)? If we can't get the demo to run, we can't implement this feature in our live app.

Here is the request sent to the server (app ID removed):

```
deadbeef=2386512837&app_id=OUR_APP_ID&api_key&receiver=0&order_info=%7B%22title%22%3A%22BFF%20Locket%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22This%20is%20a%20BFF%20Locket...%22%2C%22price%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fimages%2Fgifts%2F21.png%22%2C%22product_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fimages%2Fgifts%2F21.png%22%7D&place=app&credits_purchase=false&flow_type=BuyItem&__d=1&post_form_id=57484628313c8345bd4e904f684e43e5&fb_dtsg=1GSvy&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest
```

Here is the response returned:

```
for (;;);{"error":0,"errorSummary":"","errorDescription":"","errorIsWarning":false,"silentError":0,"payload":{"secure":false,"handler":"","title":"Application Error","userData":{"fbpayments_error":"{\"error_code\":1383008,\"error_message\":{}}"},"body":"<div class=\"pam uiBoxRed\">The application you are using is not responding.<\/div>","buttonsMessage":null,"buttons":"ok"}}
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue.. Please help I am also having the same issue. Whats the solution for this, am stuck :(

Answer (score 3):

We have updated the Facebook Credits API [sample application](https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample) and [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi). If you are still having issues, please post your frontend code as well as your callback and we can take a look.

Comment: there is only one directory named "Facebook Payments Assets" containing adobe files. I am sooo frustated and strugling to find answers. please check agoain?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue.. I was able to fix this. This error occurred for me was due the wrong call back url. I used my local_url

```
  'http://localhost:3000/blabla'
```

instead of using

```
  http://apps.facebook.com/application-name/
```